# Can I recreate a gzip file exactly, given the original uncompressed file?

Tags: compression, gzip, hashsum, archive

I have a series of `gzip` files which I wish to store more efficiently using `xz`, without losing traceability to a set of checksums of the gzip files.

I believe this amounts to being able to recreate the gzip files from the xz files, though I'm open to other suggestions.

To elaborate... If I have a gzip file named `target.txt.gz`, and I decompress it to `target.txt` and discard the compressed file, I want to exactly recreate the original compressed file `target.txt.gz`. By exactly, I mean a cryptographic checksum of the file should indicate that it is exactly the same as the original.

I initially thought this must be impossible, because a gzip file contains metadata such as original file name and timestamp, which might not be preserved upon decompression, and metadata such as a comment, the source operating system, and compression flags, which are almost certainly not preserved upon decompression.

But then I thought to modify my question: is there a minimal amount of header information that I could extract from the gzip file that, in combination with the uncompressed data, would allow me to recreate the original gzip file.

And then I thought that the answer might still be no due to the existence of tools such as [Zopfli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zopfli) and [7-zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip#Others), which can create gzip-compatible streams which are better (therefore different) from the standard gzip program. As far as I am aware, the gzip file format does not record which of these compressors created it.

So my question becomes: are there other options I haven't thought of that might mean I can achieve my goal as set out in the first paragraph after all?

Comment: It would be so much easier if you just cared about the MD5 checksum of the _uncompressed contents_ of the file...

Comment: Hopefully not MD5!

Comment: @Kusalananda: Indeed, but that's not the case unfortunately.

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, whatever type of checksum.

Comment: [Debian's advice on reproducible builds](https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds/TimestampsInGzipHeaders) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be helpful: https://github.com/google/grittibanzli

Grittibanzli is a tool to compress a deflate stream to a smaller file, which can be decoded to the original deflate stream again. That is, it compresses not only the data inside the deflate stream, but also the deflate-related information such as LZ77 symbols and Huffman trees, to reproduce a gzip, png, ... file exactly.

Comment: According to the rest of README, what it actually does is split a DEFLATE-based file into multiple files, which contain the uncompressed data plus any metadata needed to re-create the compressed file exactly. So you get to choose what compression tool to make it smaller; It doesn't do that part for you. (Originally I skimmed too quickly and was put off because I thought it could only shrink single DEFLATE files.)